# On cars with 2 Thermostats, how exactly does coolant flow through the block?

Tags: cooling-system, thermostat

How does the coolant flow in each of the following 3 cases: 1) both stats closed,
2) stat at the water inlet open (nissan calls this stat the thermostat) 
3) both stats open (nissan calls the stat at the water outlet the water control valve).
Specifically, how does the coolant flow through the block when the water control valve is closed and the thermostat at the inlet is open? Is there a complete circuit through the cooling system even with the water control valve closed?

Comment: Different engine and manufacturers can vary on how the fluid moves through the engine, what are you working on specifically?

Comment: 2008 nissan sentra 2.0 liter. The water control valve opens at 95C while the thermostat opens at 82C. It also has coolant lines running from the water outlet to the trans cooler and to the throttle actuator and to the heater core. I can't comprehend how the coolant flows. When does it flow into the radiator? When and how does it flow to the heater core and trans cooler? There must be a separate exit portal for the coolant to leave the block apart from the water control valve. Why 2 different temperatures?

Comment: I can find no technical data explaining dual thermostats in cars. Interesting question which may not get answered unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for checking. My Nissan seems to be running fine, but the temperature swings from 82C to 98C depending on the outside temp and engine conditions. Long periods of idling seem to increase the temp to the mid 90s. I just want to understand how the 2 stats are working to regulate flow and also exactly how (the path) the coolant takes out of the block under various conditions.